# Representations of finite simple groups

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

> Prove that any finite simple group $G$ has an irreducible faithful representation over $\mathbb C.$

Since 1-dimensional representations don't cover non-abelian groups, I (want to) believe that 2 is the lowest working dimension.

So, let $\rho:G\to\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb C)$ be a nontrivial representation. Since $G$ is simple, $\ker\rho=\{1\}$ and thus faithful. But what about irreducibility?

Comment: Did you try looking at some examples?

Comment: let $\rho$ have least dimension, if $\rho$ is reducible then...